# How to bind a TextBox to plain string collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

As a part of large data model I need to display/edit a string collection defined like `ObservableCollection<String>`. In prototype app we use a list view to display entire of collection and a text box to edit selected element. The text box should be bound to the current element of the collection. Because GUI is subject to change I can't bind directly using `<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=listView}" />`.

I tried to use

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=/, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

but it works only in one direction, changing listview current item causes updating a text box but not otherwise.

How can I bind a text box directly to sting instance of current element in string collection?

Comment: What do you expect your TextBox to show if it's bound to a collection of strings?

Comment: current element of collection

Comment: Ok, what defines "current" in your form? Is your TextBox inside some sort of ItemsControl, like a ListBox?

Comment: Yes, on left side I have a list view, on right side a text box for editing. List View is bound like 
'  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn Header="Data Item" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
    </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
  </ListView>'
selection changing in list view causes updating a text box but only in one way, if I change text in the text box listview not updated

Comment: Update your question with that info (so the code's nicely formatted) while I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's your ListView. I'm going to add a name to it so I can reference it elsewhere in the XAML:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name=stringList
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn 
                Header="Data Item" 
                Width="80" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now in your TextBox over on the right you can bind directly to the ListView:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=stringList}" />
```

Since your ListView is bound directly to a list of strings, SelectedItem will be the string the currently-selected ListViewItem points to.

**Update**

Since you're not allowed to use ElementBinding, your best bet is to introduce a ViewModel class to sit between your list and your window. Define it like this:

```
public class StringListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // you'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged - I won't
    // do that here - do a quick search to learn how it works.

    public ObservableCollection<String> List { get; set; }

    private object _si;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _si; }
        set
        { 
            _si = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    } 
}
```

Now set your window's DataContext to an instance of your ViewModel class instead of pointing it directly to the string list. Bind your ListView's ItemsSource and SelectedItem to it like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

Now bind your TextBox to the SelectedItem of your ViewModel:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Now your list sets the SelectedItem on the ViewModel whenever it changes, and thus your TextBox reflects that value. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it will work, but huh.. it's design question I'm not allowed to bind GUI elements directly. If I define a class with only one string property, e.g. Name, the binding works perfectly so I use this property like {Binding Path=Name}. But what is the right way to use string instances directly?

Comment: Update your question, mate. Include all the extra constraints so we can provide a meaningful answer for you.